# Trying to install a Scitools Python pkg via 'pip install' but getting error

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda, scitools

I use the Anaconda distribution of python and am trying to install an unsupported package 'scitools.'  I tried pip install but got the error as seen in the picture below. I keep getting an error. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in scitools.

Comment: Any idea how to go about installing scitools then?

Comment: No idea. You might ask at their issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/scitools/issues/list, since they don't seem to be following the questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but resolved it by manually installing all the Anaconda packages.

- NumPy
- SciPy
- Pandas
- PyTables
- h5py
- Matplotlib
- IPython
- Spyder
- Qt/PySide
- VTK
- Numexpr
- Astropy
- Cython
- LLVM
- LLVMpy
- Numba
- Scikit-learn
- Scikit-image
- NLTK
- NetworkX
- MayaVi